# enabling cpu performance counters on vmware vm

Tags: vmware, govmomi

I'm trying to use govc to `enable cpu performace counters` on a vm but can't quite figure out how to do it...in the UI I have to shut it down, enable them, and then start it back up...but I don't see an option to enable cpu performance counters in govc

Ronak Patel [7:17 PM]
specifically trying to get `VPMCEnabled` enabled
when I run `govc vm.option.info -vm "vm name"` I get that option under `Config.VPMCEnabled` but I can't figure out how to flip that flag
I've tried all of these but none seem to work:

```
govc vm.change -vm="Admin" -e vcpu.vpmc=false
govc vm.change -vm="Admin" -e vcpu.vpmcenabled=false
govc vm.change -vm="Admin" -e vpmcenabled=false
govc vm.change -vm="Admin" -e config.vpmc=false
```

I also noticed that I can change the CPU Hot add like this:

````
govc vm.change -vm="Admin" -e vcpu.hotadd=false```

but the same syntax doesn't work for the cpu performance counters
````